# ActiveAdmin belongs_to not scoping the association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have two models in Active Admin, one of which belongs to the other on a `has_many` association:

```
class Library < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :library

ActiveAdmin.register Library

ActiveAdmin.register Book do
  belongs_to :library
  navigation_menu :library
end
```

**PROBLEM**
The issue is that when accessing the page of books of a specific library (ex:`admin/libraries/123/books`), it always shows me every book available instead of the ones from the library I selected. Any ideas or is it maybe a known issue?

I'm on Rails version **4.2.0** and ActiveAdmin master branch **1.0.0.pre**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK... I just realised that specifying a `scoped_collection` like the one below breaks the belongs_to scope that ActiveAdmin includes.

```
controller do
  def scoped_collection
    Book.includes([:pages])
  end
end
```

The **solution** is to include the query in the `scoped_collection` like so:

```
controller do
  def scoped_collection
    Book.where(library_id: params[:library_id]).includes([:pages])
  end
end
```